# Error not Found value in function param which references other function param

Tags: scala

This curried version works fine. Link to Scastie [View code in action](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pckrishnadas88/XPNEYCtFTnOdHhsSbABJjg)

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int = a-1): Int = a + b
foo(9)()
```

But this version throws the Error not found value a. Link to Scastie. [View code in action](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pckrishnadas88/wvWD19RgRlqFn6DnP1RyOA)

```
def bar(a: Int, b: Int = a-1): Int = a+b
bar(9)
```

Is this an actual error or is there any reason why it is not working?

Comment: Parameters are evaluated as they are grouped. The `foo` works because the 1st group, i.e. the `a`, is evaluated before the 2nd group, the `b`. The `bar` won't compile because `a` hasn't been evaluated before it is referenced, `a-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although parameters are evaluated sequentially (and before the body of the function), `bar` fails because `a` is not in scope inside its own params list.

The scope of a parameter is only public to the subsequent params list.

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int = a - 1)(c: Int = b + a) = a + b + c 
foo(9)()()
// 34
```